# How can I keep the menu open on page reload using an accordian drop menu?

Tags: menu, accordion

I am trying to achieve keeping the menu open on the tab selected as the page reloads to the link clicked.

Here is the html code:

```
<nav>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#"><img  id="icon" src="icons/setup(48).png" />Setup</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="test.html">Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="test.html">Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="test.html">Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="test.html">Test</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><img  id="icon" src="icons/userProfile_48.png" />User Maintenance</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><img id="icon" src="icons/projects.png" />Projects</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Project Title</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project Title</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project Title</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project Title</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project Title</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project Title</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project Title</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project Title</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#nav > li > a").on("click", function(e){
         if($(this).parent().has("ul")) {
             e.preventDefault();
         }

         if(!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
         // hide any open menus and remove all other classes
             $("#nav li ul").slideUp(300);
             $("#nav li a").removeClass("open");

             // open our new menu and add the open class
             $(this).next("ul").slideDown(300);
             $(this).addClass("open");
         }

         else if($(this).hasClass("open")) {
             $(this).removeClass("open");
             $(this).next("ul").slideUp(300);
         }
     });
 });
```

At the moment it is working as it should when selecting a link and redirecting to that page but it just does not keep the menu tab open on the new page it loaded.

Some help will be great. Thanks

This part is to assist with keeping the menu open on page load.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#nav li a").click(function (e) {

        if ($(this).next("ul").length > 0) {

            e.preventDefault();     
            var navInner = $(this).next("ul");

            if (navInner.is(":visible")) {

            }

        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass the information which tab was open to the new page and reopen the tab once the page has loaded.

Two options come to mind:

- Attach the information to the link by registering an onclick-Event to modify it before the browser starts navigating to the target URL.
- Save the information in a session cookie you can access from Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I use the same script.

This is how I've solved this:

```
<li><a href="#" class="articles <?php echo ($_GET['module'] == 'articles' ? 'open': ''); ?>">Articles</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="admin.php?module=articles">Manager</a></li>
    <li><a href="admin.php?module=articles">Categories</a></li>
    <li><a href="admin.php?module=articles">Featured</a></li>
    <li><a href="admin.php?module=articles">Add</a></li>
   </ul>    
</li>
```

And add the line to JQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#nav > li > a.open").next("ul").show();  // add this line here
$("#nav > li > a").on("click", function(e){ ............
```

You can also add some class to parent `<li>` containing `<ul>` you want to have expanded
for expample articles, and then in head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu-list > li > a.articles").next("ul").show();
  });
</script>
```

I dont know if this is correct way, but it works ;)